# QGIS create boundaries from background image

Tags: qgis, polygon, boundaries

I want to manually trace over an existing map image to replicate the boundaries using QGIS.  If this was an existing polygon and I need to split this into 3 separate polygons, I would take the existing outer boundary, and then I would have to manually trace the boundaries of the inner areas - as a polyline or region? How would I join the inner boundaries to the outer boundary, and then create the 3 separate polygons within the base map table? I hope I have explained this clearly?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, my answer is what you are after. If so, the heading of your question does not reflect what you want to do. Please, edit it to help others to find similar questions

Answer (score 2):

You are after the `Polygonize` tool:

> This algorithm takes a lines layer and creates a polygon layer, with
>   polygons generated from the lines in the input layer.

You first need to convert you polygon to lines:

[image]

Then, drawing the new lines dividing the boundaries:
[image]

And here comes the `Polygonize` in the Processing Toolbox:
[image]

Voilà!

[image]

Comment: This is a lot more steps than using the Split tool. Is there any advantage to this method?

Comment: Please, go ahead with the explanation of the method, I do not know how to use it for this task

Answer (score 0):

Boundaries are usually polygons that only borders are visible. Duplicate the layer file with your big polygon, split one into multiple polygons and then edit the style to only show the borders:

[image: Outer boundary]
[image: Split, inner boundaries]
[image: Style]